# How to use assets from a directory above root in a xaringan presentation

Tags: r, xaringan

This, as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044332/can-i-set-the-css-js-paths-parametrically-in-xaringan-yaml) is related to [Issue #29](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/29), but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I would like to have images, css, .js and .R files stored in different folders that I can then use in multiple presentations. And i'd like to store the .Rmd files in individual subfolders.
Like so:

```
talks elisa$ ls
css     images      Rfunctions      js      Talk1       Talk2
```

This works:

```
---
title: "foo"
author: "Elisa"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["footer-header.css", "elisasTalk.css",  "default", "kunoichi", "ninjutsu", "metropolis-fonts"]
    lib_dir: libs
    chakra: libs/remark-latest.min.js
    seal: false
    nature:
      beforeInit: "macros.js"
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      ratio: '16:9'
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      highlightSpans: true
---
```

But, unlike the SO question, already doing:
`beforeInit: "/js/macros.js"` doesn't work for me.

How exactly can I call assets from folders in the parent directory of where my .Rmd file is using Xaringan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply link to them in the corresponding fields. To go one directory up, you can use `../`.

```
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      beforeInit: "../macros.js"
      ratio: "4:3"
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
    css: ["../mtheme.css", "../font-mtheme.css"]
```

Comment: Thank you! The only thing to note is that assets in a different folder need the extension. For me, `css: "../assets/default"`, did not work until I replaced it with `css: "../assets/default.css"`